# Display modal dialog in bootstrap when clicking anchor tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to display bootstrap modal dialog when clicking dynamically created anchor tag in jQuery. Please help me.

My code is

```
var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="announcementModal" class="morelink" href="javascript:;">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

$(this).html(html);
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: in your anchor tag this `data-target="announcementModal"` should be `data-target="#announcementModal"`

Comment: working fine, but i wants to display center of the page, the anchor tag in the bottom of the page. If i click the link it displays dialog at top of the page, so we need to scroll up to see this, but i don't like this

Comment: @GugankumarP that's not the bootstrap modal default behaviour, something else in your CSS causing the problem

Comment: @GugankumarP doesn't matter where on page the modal trigger button exist, modal will always show `on screen` no need to scroll up or down to find the modal, check your body css properties and also make sure you have modal HTML at bottom of the page (always at the bottom of the page before `</body>` tag) not somewhere in the middle or top of page

Comment: @Shehary my modal shows only top of the page. I need to scroll top to see the popup. I don't know what is the problem